# Parametized update using Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am converting a winforms application from MS Access to SQLServer Express.

I have some code which is used throughout the application for updating the database, I pass in the table name, ID for the entry the fields to update and the values in an array... works ok with access

The code generates an SQL statememnt, which is passed as a query along with the values as parameters... an example output is

`UPDATE userVersion SET lastUpdated=?, userId=?, userName=?, version=? WHERE userId = 1299`

if I try run this on sqlserver, the system crashes with this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '?'.
>   Incorrect syntax near '?'.'

What is the correct format for sql server?

Comment: If you googled first you'd already have your answer. Do a search for how to use `SqlParameter`.

Comment: Search first on google

Comment: fair comment, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error you are using SQLClient to execute the query, but the structure of the query looks like it may be closer to ODBC's command.

In case it helps, System.Data.ODBC.ODBCCommand uses the "?" symbol as a place holder for parameters. The order of the parameters is important in this case.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

The System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand uses named variables (for example @MyVariable) to specify variables. In this case, order is not important as long as the names are specified correctly.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

ODBCCommand would look like:

```
UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics WHERE CustomerID = ?;
```

While SQLCommand would look like:

```
UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics WHERE CustomerID = @ID;
```